# Prevent UserControl from loading ResourceDictionaries

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, resourcedictionary

I am currently implementing printing with threading. So far there are (almost) no issues.
I was stuck a while with xaml parse exceptions, though I got it fixed by adding ResourceDictionaries to the view I want to print. The view was apparently going to try and load the ResourceDictionaries defined in the test project's `app.xaml` in its `InitializeComponent` call.
*We're using themes which can be changed at runtime. They also have some global styles.*

*Now to the question...* is there a way I can prevent the `UserControl` from loading the ResourceDictionaries defined in `app.xaml` or from any other location in `InitializeComponent` ?

Basically all views in the application are using the current theme with styles, and the `UserControl`s for printing should use no style and no `ResourceDictionary` at all.

Comment: The way dictionaries work is that is that they cascade down the visual tree

so if your control has a dictionary with the correct key that value is returned, if not then it asks the parent and then the parents parent, and so on until it hits the App

so you can't prevent it loading from the app, but you can locally override the App's resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" the problem by creating a new theme, which overrides all used control styles by default. Only including this `ResourceDictionary` in the `UserControl` resources will use WPF default styles.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyAssembly;component/Themes/Theme.Nothing.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

A few lines of the `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Slider}"/>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}"/>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}"/>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"/>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"/>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}"/>
```